# A Question About Euler's Factorization Method

Tags: algebra-precalculus, prime-factorization

I'm trying to understand Euler's factorization method from this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_factorization_method. What I don't understand is when the article states "As each factor is a sum of two squares, one of these must contain both even numbers: either (k,h) or (l,m)". Why does the fact that each factor is a sum of two squares, mean one of these must contain both even numbers?

Comment: The equation says $(k^2+h^2)(l^2+m^2)=4n$, hence $4$ divides the product.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I understand that, but to my understanding, just because (^2+ℎ^2)(^2+^2) = 4n doesn't mean any of k,h,l,m are even. If all of k,h,l,m were odd, then we would have 2 even numbers multiplied together, which would still give us 4n. So how does the fact that  each factor is a sum of two squares, mean one of these must contain both even numbers?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Can I get bit more of a hint? Because I still don't see how this proves that any of k^2, h^2, l^2 or m^2 is divisible by 4. Thanks

Comment: Right, the construction given before must be important, too.

Comment: a more readable presentation by Brillhart: http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Brillhart_Euler_factoring_2009.pdf

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks so much that helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

I think the key to recognizing that either (k,h) or (l,m) must be even is to recognize that either factor must be an integer multiple of 4. That is, either $(k^2 + h^2)$ or $(l^2 + m^2)$ must be divisible by 4. This means either (k,h) or (l,m) must be divisible by 2 and thus even.